# How to find center dots of given dots in radius of 16 (x;z)?

Tags: java, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to print out locations of center dots. Compared dots must be in radius of 16. Printing out only if there is more than 5 dots in one place calculating from center.

**Center dot is, which is nearest to all nearby dots**

[image]

My code is giving me false positives and duplicates. Methods:

```java
    HashMap<Location, HashSet<Location>> map = new HashMap<Location, HashSet<Location>>();
    for (LocationCopy loc : locs) {
            HashSet<LocationCopy> locsCopy = new HashSet<LocationCopy>(locs);
            locsCopy.remove(loc);
            for (LocationCopy loc2 : locsCopy) {
                if (distance(loc2.getX(),loc.getX(),loc2.getZ(),loc.getZ()) <= 16) {
                    if (!map.containsKey(loc.getLoc())) {
                        HashSet<Location> hs = new HashSet<Location>();
                        hs.add(loc2.getLoc());
                        map.put(loc2.getLoc(), hs);
                    } else {
                        HashSet<Location> hs = map.get(loc.getLoc());
                        hs.add(loc2.getLoc());
                        map.put(loc2.getLoc(), hs);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for (Location loc : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(loc).size() > 5) {
                write("More than " + map.get(loc).size() + locToString(loc) + ": " + getLocs(map.get(loc)) + "<br>", fileName, beta);
            }
        }

    private double distance(double x1, double x2, double z1, double z2){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.pow(z2-z1,2));
    }
```

Class:

```java
    public class LocationCopy {
        private int x, y, z;
        private String world;

        public LocationCopy(int x, int y, int z, String world) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
            this.world = world;
        }

        public LocationCopy(Location spawner) {
            this.x = spawner.getBlockX();
            this.y = spawner.getBlockY();
            this.z = spawner.getBlockZ();
            this.world = spawner.getWorld().getName();
        }

        public int getX(){
            return x;
        }

        public int getZ(){
            return z;
        }

        public Location getLoc() {
            return new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(world), x, y, z);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are serval small problems in your code:

- `map.put(loc2.getLoc(), hs);` should be `map.put(loc.getLoc(), hs);` instead
- You need to add a `hashCode` method to your classes, because otherwhise the `HashSet`s you use will not be able to identify objects that represent the same location
- You only search for groups of points, not for their centers

A solution could look like this (implemented your method in the class LocationCopy, because no class was shown in your question):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class LocationCopy {

    private int x, y, z;
    //private String world;

    public LocationCopy(int x/*, int y*/, int z/*, String world*/) {
        this.x = x;
        //this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        //this.world = world;
    }

    public LocationCopy(Location spawner) {
        this.x = spawner.getBlockX();
        this.y = spawner.getBlockY();
        this.z = spawner.getBlockZ();
        //this.world = spawner.getWorld().getName();
    }

    //EDIT added toString method (just for better printing and debugging)
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationCopy [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z + "]";
    }

    //EDIT: added hashCode method that is needed for the HashSets to identify objects that represent the same location
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        result = prime * result + z;
        return result;
    }

    //EDIT: added equals method (not really needed, but better to have one...)
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        LocationCopy other = (LocationCopy) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        if (z != other.z)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public Location getLoc() {
        return new Location(x, y, z);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LocationCopy> locs = createLocs();

        HashMap<Location, HashSet<Location>> map = new HashMap<Location, HashSet<Location>>();
        for (LocationCopy loc : locs) {
            HashSet<LocationCopy> locsCopy = new HashSet<LocationCopy>(locs);
            locsCopy.remove(loc);
            for (LocationCopy loc2 : locsCopy) {
                if (distance(loc2.getX(), loc.getX(), loc2.getZ(), loc.getZ()) <= 16) {
                    if (!map.containsKey(loc.getLoc())) {
                        HashSet<Location> hs = new HashSet<Location>();
                        hs.add(loc2.getLoc());
                        map.put(loc.getLoc(), hs);//EDIT: changed loc2 to loc
                    }
                    else {
                        HashSet<Location> hs = map.get(loc.getLoc());
                        hs.add(loc2.getLoc());
                        map.put(loc.getLoc(), hs);//EDIT: changed loc2 to loc
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //EDIT: selecting groups for finding the center
        Set<Set<Location>> groups = new HashSet<Set<Location>>();

        for (Location loc : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(loc).size() > 5) {
                //EDIT: don't know what write does -> using System.out.println instead
                //write("More than " + map.get(loc).size() + locToString(loc) + ": " + getLocs(map.get(loc)) + "<br>", fileName, beta);
                System.out.println("More than " + map.get(loc).size() + " " + locToString(loc) + ": " + /*getLocs(map.get(loc)) + */"<br>");

                //EDIT: create groups to find the center points
                Set<Location> group = new HashSet<Location>();
                group.addAll(map.get(loc));
                group.add(loc);

                groups.add(group);
            }
        }

        //EDIT: find the center of the group
        for (Set<Location> group : groups) {
            Location center = findCenter(group);

            System.out.println("center found: " + center);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find the center of each group by calculating the summed distance from each point to every other point.
     * 
     * The point that has the minimum summed distance to every other point is the center.
     */
    private static Location findCenter(Set<Location> group) {
        if (group.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The group mussn't be empty");
        }

        List<LocationDistance> summedDistances = new ArrayList<LocationDistance>(group.size());

        for (Location loc : group) {
            LocationDistance dist = new LocationDistance(loc, 0);
            //sum up the distance to each location in the group
            for (Location loc2 : group) {
                double distance = distance(loc.getBlockX(), loc2.getBlockX(), loc.getBlockZ(), loc2.getBlockZ());
                dist.setDistance(dist.getDistance() + distance);
            }
            summedDistances.add(dist);
        }

        //sort the list (LocationDistance implements Comparable to do this)
        Collections.sort(summedDistances);

        //the first item in the list is the center
        return summedDistances.get(0).getLocation();
    }

    private static List<LocationCopy> createLocs() {
        List<LocationCopy> locs = new ArrayList<LocationCopy>();

        //trying to create the example from the image in your question
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(0, 0));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(2, 0));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(5, 0));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(1, 2));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(2, 1));//center
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(4, 1));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(3, 2));//adding a new point because otherwhise it will never be enough for a group greater than 5
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(10, 30));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(12, 31));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(15, 31));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(8, 36));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(13, 33));//center
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(18, 34));
        locs.add(new LocationCopy(15, 36));//adding a new point because otherwhise it will never be enough for a group greater than 5

        return locs;
    }

    private static String locToString(Location loc) {
        return loc.getBlockX() + " " + loc.getBlockY() + " " + loc.getBlockZ();
    }

    private static double distance(double x1, double x2, double z1, double z2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(z2 - z1, 2));
    }
}
```

The class Location (the important part is the `hashCode` method):

```
public class Location {

    public int x, y, z;

    public Location(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public int getBlockX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getBlockY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getBlockZ() {
        return z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Location [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z=" + z + "]";
    }

    //EDIT here the hashCode is also important for the HashSets you use in your code
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        result = prime * result + z;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Location other = (Location) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        if (z != other.z)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and a new class LocationDistance for comparing distances:

```
/**
 * A class for comparing the distances for locations
 */
public class LocationDistance implements Comparable<LocationDistance> {

    private Location location;
    private double distance;

    public LocationDistance(Location location, double distance) {
        this.location = location;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationDistance [location=" + location + ", distance=" + distance + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LocationDistance other) {
        return Double.compare(distance, other.getDistance());
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
More than 6 2 0 0: <br>
More than 6 1 0 2: <br>
More than 6 2 0 1: <br>
More than 6 5 0 0: <br>
More than 6 4 0 1: <br>
More than 6 3 0 2: <br>
More than 6 10 0 30: <br>
More than 6 12 0 31: <br>
More than 6 8 0 36: <br>
More than 6 15 0 31: <br>
More than 6 13 0 33: <br>
More than 6 15 0 36: <br>
More than 6 18 0 34: <br>
More than 6 0 0 0: <br>

center found: Location [x=2, y=0, z=1]
center found: Location [x=13, y=0, z=33]
```

Here the last two lines are the centers you were searching for.